# IIS ASP NET Works on FireFox but not on CHROME

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, iis

I am developing a web service under ASP NET CORE 2.1 deployed on IIS.
I have a redirect problem with CHROME.
As the view below shows, following authentication via SSO (1), with FIREFOX, I am correctly redirected to the index of my site (2), while with CHROME, it seems that I redirects again to SSO (3).

[image]

Do you have any idea of the problem?

Just for precision

[image]

Comment: No matter what's the cause, ASP.NET Core 2.1 is end of life. You will have to upgrade first to a supported version so as to make this question valid for further discussion.

Comment: I understand, but I am not responsible for upgrading this already existing web serice, I would like, however, but simply to add SSO authentication and some improvements.

Comment: I had permission to migrate the application to ASP NET 3.1, as this we are up to date. But unfortunately the problem on CHROME remains unresolved...

Comment: Since you opened the network tab, what's exactly in Response (Headers are of little usage for 500 troubleshooting)? Usually the 500 error response itself is a full page of hints.

Comment: Just: "Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found"

Comment: Nobody can help me about it?

Comment: Usually people have to access your machine so as to debug further. You'd better hire a personal consultant, or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com That's not something you expect a forum can help.

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to this error description in **google chrome** specially when you use cookie-base authentication :

> Cookies marked with SameSite=None must also be marked with Secure to allow setting them in a cross-site context. This behavior protects user data from being sent over an insecure connection.
> Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
> Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie is intended to be set in cross-site contexts. Note that only cookies sent over HTTPS may use the Secure attribute.
> Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be set by cross-site requests.

You need to change cookie settings in your authentication or you need to sign your SSL certificate on your server .

[image]

If you find this useful please vote up ;)